# What is dead beat reading?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, measurements

I was reading about characteristic of a comparator.
It states
Comparator indicator device should be such that the readings are obtained in least possible time and for this magnification system should be such that the readings are dead beat.And there should be no backlash

Can someone kindly explain what is dead beat reading and an example about blacklash in comparator

Thank you

Comment: What is a comparator in this context? Can you link to the article?

Comment: It's mechanical comparator

Comment: And the link to the article?